# Why am i not able to import Gesture, GestureDetector from react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I get the errors: *Module `react-native-gesture-handler` has no exported member 'Gesture'.* and *Module `react-native-gesture-handler` has no exported member 'GestureDetector'* respectively but these are members mentioned in the React Native Gesture Handler doc.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot] .

Any idea why I'm not able to use Gesture and GestureDetector even after running `npm i react-native-gesture-handler`?